# How can I login a form with captcha using capybara?

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I am wonder that was it possible to log in a form which has captcha using capybara?I don't know if there some libs available for me or some tricks to do that. Every answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-fill the value of the captcha to the form conditionally when running in Rails.env.test?, something like:

```
<%= f.text_field :captcha, value: (Rails.env.test? ? captcha_value : nil) %>
```

The point of captchas is that they can't be [easily] machine read. With the above you can at least test that, given the correct input value, your form properly processes the captcha.